# ERROR 1064 (42000) caused by PAGE_CHECKSUM

Tags: mysql, innodb

My sql file:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
set FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `wp_icl_core_status`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_icl_core_status` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `module` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `origin` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `target` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `status` smallint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `rid` (`rid`)
) ENGINE=Aria DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 PAGE_CHECKSUM=1;
```

Upon loading it to my table I get following error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PAGE_CHECKSUM=1' at line 10
```

Following the error I removed `PAGE_CHECKSUM=1` from line 10 and I was able to proceed with loading the sql file in my require table.

**My Question**

Why did I get the error at first place? Is `PAGE_CHECKSUM` not supported with my MySql version? If not whats the alternative (other than plainly removing it)

**MySql details:**

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                   |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.5.38                  |
| protocol_version        | 10                      |
| slave_type_conversions  |                         |
| version                 | 5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 |
| version_comment         | (Ubuntu)                |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                  |
| version_compile_os      | debian-linux-gnu        |

+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be moving from a host that used MariaDB to one that uses MySQL (and BTW, you gave us versions of PHP and not of MySQL - they're two different things). Try changing `ENGINE=Aria` to `ENGINE=MyISAM` and remove `PAGE_CHECKSUM=`1 part as `MyISAM` does not support it.

check this and comment me.

Comment: that makes so much sense. Thanks a lot, not really an expert on MySql engines.

Comment: I needed not to change the ENGINE removing `PAGE_CHECKSUM` was good enough, however I was looking for the reason(explanation). Your answer pointed me to the right direction. So thanks :)